# Error during upload - Android

Tags: android, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload image as multipart data(image and size) to server. I used flask server. I tried to send data on server and get no errors in application but when it comes to sending, it never uploads but shows error during upload. I checked server with postman and it works fine. I am providing code:

```
public void uploadMultipart() {
    //getting name for the image
    String name = editText.getText().toString().trim();
    //getting the actual path of the image
    String path = getPath(filePath);
    Integer size = 0;
    //Uploading code
    File file = new File(path);
    Bitmap bf = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    Integer height = bf.getHeight();
    Integer width = bf.getWidth();
    size = width*height;
    try {
        //Creating a multi part request
        new MultipartUploadRequest(this.getApplicationContext(), "", Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                .addFileToUpload(path, "file") //Adding file
                .addParameter("size", size.toString()) //Adding text parameter to the request
                .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                .setMaxRetries(2)
                .setDelegate(new UploadServiceBroadcastReceiver())
                .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}`
```

Comment: What's the error during upload?

Comment: What is your upload url and content type?

Comment: File upload - error during upload is the only message i get on display of my phone. UPLOAD_URL="http://147.91.11.2:5000/v1/rpc/upload" 
I didn't set content type.